# How many different ordered triples are there such that $a+b+c = 50$ and $a\geq b\geq c\geq 0$? What if $a>b>c>0$?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

How many different ordered triples are there such that $a+b+c = 50$ and $a\geq b\geq c\geq 0$? What if $a>b>c>0$?
a,b, and c are all integers

I found this question from a textbook, but the author didn't give the answer so I don't know if my answers are correct, can anyone help me with this problem?

My answers:

if $a\geq b\geq c\geq 0$: $221$ possible triples

if $a>b>c>0$: $196$ possible triples

Thanks!

Comment: Your answers are not in [OEIS A001399](https://oeis.org/A001399) so are unlikely to correct. (I suspect the first is too small and the second too large)  How did you calculate them?

Comment: stars and bars, for both problems.

Comment: $a=x+y+z$, $b=x+y$, $c=x$ with $x,y,z\geq 0$ for the first one and $x,y,z>0$ for the second

Comment: So your $221={50+2 \choose 2}/3!$ and $196={50-1 \choose 2}/3!$ A nice idea but sadly  stars and bars will not deal with the inequalities accurately. You can see this with a total of $6$: stars and bars would give the obviously wrong  $4.667$ and $1.667$ when the correct answers would be $7$ and $1$

Comment: I assume you are restricting yourself to integers,  otherwise the answer is trivially infinite...still nice to state

Comment: I suggest:  count all the triples (ignoring restrictions).  Then count the ones in which two of the variables are equal (all three equal is not possible).  Answering those questions gives you enough to solve the problem, with some further effort.

Comment: There are infinitely many such triples. But I suppose the question also states that $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1):

**REVISITED BY CHANCE AND A SIMPLE ANSWER OFFERED**

*PART 1*

All three numbers obviously can't be the same.
Of the $\binom{52}2 = 1326$ solutions given by stars and bars,
there will be $26\;\;$ with $\;\;2-1\;of\; a\; kind:\; 0-0-50\;\; to\;\; 25-25-0$
each with $3$ permutations
So distinct triples with $6$ permutations each $= 1326 - 3*26 = 1248$
and final answer $= \frac{1248}6+26 =\boxed{234}$

---

**PART TWO**

This time, we want all three digits to be different.
There will be a total of $\binom{49}2 = 1176$ arrangements
of which this time $24$ will be $2-1\;\;of\;a\;kind$
and final answer = $(1176 -24*3)/6 = \boxed{184}$

Comment: I am not so certain this approach works, as this does not match up with [my computer analysis](https://tio.run/##TY7BDoMgEETvfMXcKpEYtfHSBP4FEFuSFgzioV9PlVLtaXffzGZmfseHd9eUtF9d7MDRkrz2eZ18gIZ1CNLdTTV09EawQ3VCzfDlWZCnoA4BdoKsVa05H9oMUPJqji7fu0MoSDdCCZ2nFsWL0ugwEzIH62J1cetLmQA/wYfRBDMiBjs/zYJKMsU0xdLEpmRv0Rf6@5SCK8G14Btkpc2fuHUQp9LTlD4) by an entire order of magnitude.

Comment: @trueblueanil Definitely your answer is wrong.

Comment: @MohammadAliNematollahi: I had misconstrued the question. On revisiting by chance, I have corrected.

Comment: @BrianMoehring:  had misconstrued the question. On revisiting by chance, I have corrected.

Comment: @Graviton:  had misconstrued the question. On revisiting by chance, I have corrected.

Answer (score 1):

We set the followings:

$$
\begin{align}
a&=x+y+z\\
b&=x+y\\
c&=x\\
\\
0&\leq x,y,z\\
\\
50&=3x+2y+z
\end{align}
$$

First let’s evaluate the number of solutions with even $x$

$$
\begin{align}
x&=2k\\
k&\in(0,1,…,8)\\
y&\in(0,…,25-3k)
\end{align}
$$

Next, let’s evaluate the number of solutions with odd $x$

$$
\begin{align}
x&=2k+1\\
k&\in(0,…,7)\\
y&\in(0,…,23-3k)
\end{align}
$$

That bring our total solutions to

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{8}{\left(26-3k\right)}+\sum_{k=0}^{7}{\left(24-3k\right)}=234
$$

For the second case, simply solve for $3x+2y+z=44$. Hope you understand enough to work on it yourself

Answer (score 0):

*Using generating functions:*

First rewrite the problem by using the substitutions
$$d = a-b, \qquad e = b-c, \qquad f = c.$$
so we have $d,e,f \geq 0$ are integers such that $d + 2e + 3f = 50$.

The number of such triplets can be found as the coefficient of $x^{50}$ in the generating function
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)}$$

By using partial fractions, we may find,
$$\begin{align*}\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)} &= \frac{17x^2-52x+47}{72(1-x)^3} + \frac{1}{8(1+x)} + \frac{1}{3(1-x^3)} - \frac{1}{9(1-x)} \\ &= \frac{17x^2-52x+47}{72}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+2}{2}x^n + \frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n + \frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{3n} - \frac{1}{9}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \end{align*}$$
giving an answer of
$$\frac{17}{72}\binom{50}{2} - \frac{52}{72}\binom{51}{2} + \frac{47}{72}\binom{52}{2} + \frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{9} = 234$$
for the first problem.

---

For the second problem, you would have $d,e,f > 0$, or by another substitution of $d' = d-1, e'=e-1, f'=f-1$ we'd be counting the number of triples $d',e',f' \geq 0$ such that $d' + 2e' + 3f' = 44$, so it's just the coefficient of $x^{44}$ of the same generating function.  This gives
$$\frac{17}{72}\binom{44}{2} - \frac{52}{72}\binom{45}{2} + \frac{47}{72}\binom{46}{2} + \frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{9} = 184$$